# header and footer not appearing on first page of contents, list of figures and list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

My report contains a table of contents spanning three pages, and a list of figures page spanning three pages, and a table of contents on a single page. Unfortunately the header and footer is not appearing on the first page of contents, as well as the first page of list of figures, and it isn't appearing on the list of tables page as well.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \rfoot{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{xyz}
\lhead{year}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.6pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.6pt}
\lfoot{blah}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\hypersetup{linkcolor = black}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\listoffigures
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill\textbf{Pg.No}\par}


\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\listoftables
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill\textbf{Pg.No}\par}

\chapter{Title}

dummy text.

\end{document}
```

How do I make the header and footer to appear on the first pages of contents, list of figures, and list of tables?

Comment: Load the package `etoolbox` and your patch will work.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel The patch is working for chapters after loading the
etoolbox package. I still don't get the  header and footer
on the required pages.

Comment: Your example provides the following output: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BsuZY.png

Comment: this topic also covered in [How to get header and footer over ToC, LoF and Nomeclature?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42912/579)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Strange that I'm not getting that, is there any other package that is in conflict with the etoolbox package?

Comment: another candidate for duplicate: [Header and Footer on multipage listoffigures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82869/579)

Comment: No i used your example. Sorry for the silly question but did you load `etoolbox` before the command `patchcmd`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Yes I did load the etoolbox package. barbara's reference to the example in the second link worked, but thank you for your prompt replies.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The second example you referred to helped. Thank You!!